# addTextChangedListener Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Been looking at other questions but none of them solved my problem.

I have an editText and I need to implement an addTextChangedListener to this field so i can update values of other text views in real time.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText billText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.billValue);
    billText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    });
```

Anything wrong in my code that I may be missing?

Comment: what/where is the problem?

Comment: post your `activity_main.xml` layout and also post error `LogCat`.

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: billText is null, post activity_main layout code

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can guess, following line causing `NullPointerException` because your `editText` is `null`

```
billText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
```

May be the `EditText` you are trying to access here isn't in the `activity_main.xml` layout. So at first, make sure that the `EditText` with id `billValue` exists in the `activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of an interface not a class. Instead, you may write your activity class as

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TextWatcher
```

and add some methods to your class:

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
            int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Try it, you will not have an exception I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Do like the following -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    billText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {           
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, 
      int start, int before, int count)
      {
        EditText billText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.billText);
        billText_val = billText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();             
        //do anything with this value

      }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing that fine There Might be an Issue with the Reference of your EditText

Anyhow here is my sample code attached for this purpose.

```
et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_regstepone_email);

et_email.addTextChangedListener(this);

    @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(count==0&&et_email.length()==0){
        et_email.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);

    }else if(count>0){

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. 
Check the ID of your `EditText` in other layout xml files of the same activity. In my case it was the xml in `layout-v21`. I was overriding the ID of the `EditText` element in it.

[image]